# I would like to have two zoomable UIImageViews...on the same view, but I can't get it to work!

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nested, zooming

Ok I have been working on this feature for some time now and it is driving me nuts. I have looked all around the web and can't seem to find any answer. I want to have a view that has two UIScrollviews, that themselves contain a UIImageView each. So I can have to images on my view that are SEPARATELY scroll/zoomable.

It seems pretty simple, but I just can't get it to work. I setup the ScrollView/ImageView pairs in IB and hooked them up ok. Now my viewDidLoad code looks like this:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
// set the image to be displayed, pic your own image here

imageView = [[MyImage alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"newBackground.png"]];

// yes we want to allow user interaction

[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

// set the instance of our myScrollView to use the main screen

scrollView = [[MyScroll alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

// turn on scrolling

[scrollView setScrollEnabled: YES];

// set the content size to the size of the image

[scrollView setContentSize: imageView.image.size];

// add the instance of our myImageView class to the content view

[scrollView addSubview: imageView];

// flush the item

[imageView release];

// set max zoom to what suits you

[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1.0f];

// set min zoom to what suits you

[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.25f];

// set the delegate

[scrollView setDelegate: self];

// scroll a portion of image into view (my image is very big) :)

//[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 440) animated:NO];

// yes to autoresize

scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

// set the mask

scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

// set the view

//self.view =scrollView;

[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)];

self.view =scrollView;

imageView1 = [[MyImage alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"newBackground.png"]];

// yes we want to allow user interaction

[imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

// set the instance of our myScrollView to use the main screen

scrollView1 = [[MyScroll alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

// turn on scrolling

[scrollView1 setScrollEnabled: YES];

// set the content size to the size of the image

[scrollView1 setContentSize: imageView1.image.size];

// add the instance of our myImageView class to the content view

[scrollView1 addSubview: imageView1];

// flush the item

[imageView1 release];

// set max zoom to what suits you

[scrollView1 setMaximumZoomScale:1.0f];

// set min zoom to what suits you

[scrollView1 setMinimumZoomScale:0.25f];

// set the delegate

[scrollView1 setDelegate: self];

// scroll a portion of image into view (my image is very big) :)

//[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 440) animated:NO];

// yes to autoresize

scrollView1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

// set the mask

scrollView1.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

// set the view

//self.view =scrollView;

[scrollView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 220)];

//I do this only because I don't know what else to do. This effectively adds the scrollview to the scrollview...
self.view =scrollView1;
```

And the first scrollView loads, but then the second one is nested in that one! I tried doing`[self.view addSubView:scrollView1];` but that just made the app crash. I'm trying my best to really dig in and figure out scrollViews as best I can, but I am just getting owned here.

Please help!

Thanks

** To further clarify, all I want is to have a scrollView on the top half of an image that can pan and zoom with an image inside of it, and then another scrollView separate from the firt that can pan and zoom on the bottom half of the screen, independent of the first.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both scroll views as subviews of the ViewController's view (self.view):

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView1];
```

You'll then need to manually position those views so they're positioned like you want them (the above code will put the two scroll views on top of each other, with some arbitrary default size which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your answer. I got both the scrollViews to show the right content in the right places! Now, however, there is an issue with the zooming. If I pinch inside of the first scrollView, the first image zooms fine. If I pinch inside of the second scrollView, the first image zooms! And the second scrollView gets bigger...as if the image is increasing in size, but it isn't...any ideas?